# How to import only specific columns from CSV in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

PostgreSQL version: 9.6

I have a table `xyz` with columns `a integer`, `b integer`, `c text`, `d integer`.

The column `c` has a non-null constraint.

I have a CSV looking like so:

foo.csv

```
1,4
2,5
3,7
```

How could I only update column `a` and `d` by importing the CSV above?

I tried `COPY xyz (a,d) FROM '/foo.csv' DELIMITER ',';` but it gave me an error

`ERROR:  null value in column "c" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, null, 4).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a `not null` column should have a default value defined. You can define a default value for an existing column, e.g.

```
alter table xyz alter c set default '';
```

After that, the copy command will succeed.

Comment: Thank you for a comment @klin. Yes, you usually have a default value. The column `c` is actually an ActiveRecord default column `created_at` if you are familiar with Ruby on Rails. It doesn't have a default value as Rails automatically appends a value to it whether it is a good strategy or not. I'm also curious about the way to achieve this without running `ALTER TABLE` as all I want to do for now is to import values to the table from some CSV for once. Again, thank you, this is a legit option.

Comment: Well, you can always drop the constraint when it is not necessary anymore.